# Cross-post to Apple Developers forums - what should I do?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just found a person who posted the exact same question both on Ask Different and on Apple Developers forums. I just asked them if it was them and they said "yes".

What should I do about it?

It's not cross-posting across different sites of the SE network so I'm unsure of what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can‘t hinder people from posting their question all over the Internet, discuss it with friends, ask their dog about it etc., so basically there is nothing to do.

What we sometimes see are questions which just say „I have this and that problem, see (Apple Discussion link) for the full description“. Such questions should be flagged/put on hold for lack of details.

Comment: Okay. If there's an answer on Apple Developers forum, I could post it here to help AD users right?

Comment: @thinkr If you copy answers from other sites, please make sure to verify them yourself, and to provide a link to the original source.

Comment: Of course! I was just asking if I could do that.

Comment: Keep in mind @Thinkr since developer forums are for developer specific items and we are not for code specific problems, the chance that a question is on topic both places is low. As long as the question is good and the answer isn't plagiarism there may be some chances where cross post fits and is worth the effort.

Comment: @thinkr The [actual question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460740/api-for-uwb-and-airtag-in-wwdc23?noredirect=1) is clearly off-topic for various reasons.

Comment: Yeah. I saw that.